# Синхронизация двух потоков

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте возник вопрос в синхронизации отдельной части приложения, вот пример:

```
class Server : public IServer
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> SPtrClientSocket;
    ...
    void startServer() override;
    void stopServer() override;
private:
    ...
    void addClient(const SPtrClientSocket& client);
    void removeClient();
private:
    ...
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::queue<SPtrClientSocket> _clients;
};

void Server::addClient(const SPtrClientSocket& client)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    _clients.push(client);
}

void Server::removeClient()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    _clients.pop();
}
```

Как видно из примера, у меня есть сервер на который коннектятся клиенты. Один поток слушает соединение и добавляет клиентов в очередь, другой потом выполняет какие-либо действия с этим клиентом отправляет ему результат и удаляет из очереди. В связи с этим я немного сомневаюсь в правильности моей синхронизации не получится ли UD? Может кто-нибудь расскажет наиболее оптимальный вариант синхронизации для данного случая? Заранее спасибо...

Answer (score 2):

Должен быть код ожидания событий (не предоставил) в котором при получении должен блокироваться `mtx`. (`condition_variable`, `wait`, `notify_one`) Сервер при посылании события должен лочить `mtx`, и обработчик тоже. **Mutex** и **queue** и **condition_variable** должны быть доступны **И** серверу **И** обработчику.